# Ansible - Could not find imported module support code for 'Ansible.ModuleUtils.PrivilegeUtil'

Tags: ansible

I'm for some reason unable to create registry keys using the win_regedit module.
The weird thing is that it has previously worked but now I'm stuck with the following error message:

```
{"msg": "Could not find imported module support code for 'Ansible.ModuleUtils.PrivilegeUtil'."}
```

Currently running ansible-playbook 2.4.3.0.
I've tried to locate the module named 'ModuleUtils.PrivilegeUtil' with no luck.

**Playbook**

```
- name: Add or update registry path, with entry 'ForceAutoLogon'
  win_regedit:
    path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
    name: ForceAutoLogon
    data: 0
    type: string
```

I'm quite new to Ansible I might add, is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Best regards

Comment: Hi leffeloket, welcome to SO. So, good news and bad news: good news is [there is an existing issue for that](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/45680), bad news is that it was inexplicably closed without comment or resolution. You are using an **absolutely ancient** version of ansible, so if at all possible, try again with a modern version and see if that issue persists

Comment: Thanks! Will do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after updating ansible.